# How memory is allocated for Stack and Queue in java

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

We know ArrayList uses dynamic array to store data. LinkedList uses linked list to store data. So, for both these case we know how it works when there is a new element added or deleted(Memory wise). Now similarly, how memory is allocated for a Stack or Queue in java. What happens, at Memory level, when I add/delete element to/from Stack or Queue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `Queue` is an interface, so not much to say about that. There's a lot of implementations and different behaviours. Anyway, for instance, `ArrayBlockingQueue` has a memory allocation similar to `ArrayList`. Anyway, there are two major groups (bounded and unbounded) but it will really depend on the implementation you choose.

About `Stack`, the memory allocation is also pretty similar to `ArrayList` as it's a subclass of `Vector` and this is backed by an array.

Answer (score -1):

`java.util.Stack` is a subclass of `java.util.Vector` which is nothing but an array. Now `java.util.Queue` is an interface and has various implementations which are divided into two primary categories:

1. bounded - backed by an underlying array of fixed size. A common example is `ArrayBlockingQueue`
2. unbounded - backed by a linked list and hence theoretically infinite. A common example is `LinkedBlockingQueue`

Please check the docs for [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) and [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)